# How to resize QListWidgetItem according to it's content?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I'm adding a QListWidgetItems to a QListWidget. Is there any way to set the size of the QListWidgetItem according to it's content data?

```cpp
QSize size(50, 20);
QListWidgetItem* newItem1 = new QListWidgetItem();
newItem1->setText("short text");
newItem1->setSizeHint(size);
listWidget->addItem(newItem1); //listWidget is previously created
QListWidgetItem* newItem2 = new QListWidgetItem();
newItem2->setText("this is a very long text");
newItem2->setSizeHint(size);
listWidget->addItem(newItem2);
```

Text of newItem1 is displayed without any problem. But the newItem2 text is not fully displayed. It only shows few characters and then "..." as text elide. How to show the complete text without the elide? I want to set the size according to the size of item's data without setting any constant numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have accidentally enabled uniformItemSizes for the QListWidget. When I disable that, QListWidgetItems were automatically resized according to it's content.

Answer (score 0):

I simply copy/pasted your code, removed `setSizeHint()` function call for both items and added some of mine. Here's working code:

```
QListWidgetItem* newItem1 = new QListWidgetItem();
newItem1->setText("short text");
ui->listWidget->addItem(newItem1); 
QListWidgetItem* newItem2 = new QListWidgetItem();
newItem2->setText("this is a very long text");
ui->listWidget->addItem(newItem2);
ui->listWidget->setFixedSize(ui->listWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0) + ui->listWidget->frameWidth() * 2,
                             ui->listWidget->sizeHintForRow(0) * ui->listWidget->count() + 2 * ui->listWidget->frameWidth());
```

[image]

As you can see, both items are fully displayed.